# License header API

Tags: api, web-apis

Is there an API, or simply some static HTTP/FTP server, which provides the license header for a license, given its SPDX ID? I know websites like choosealicense.com provide an API for getting the full license file, but I want to extract the particular part about license headers, because I'm making a tool that checks the license headers in a project.

I know that for Maven there exists a plugin called [license-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/license-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/licenses), but the plugin ships its own license header store (and fetching their GitHub is not a stable API). Do we have an online alternative?